# Android: How can I play private videos with Youtube Player API

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am using Youtube Data API and Youtube Player API for my video app. I obtained a token from Youtube DATA api and got access to user private videos.

How can I play them for him? I saw no place to set a token in Youtube Player API.

Comment: may be this , https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/iUU5KYSezPs  help. He's saying you can play it using rtsp link but with less quality. FYI , I haven't triend it though.